# Should Stack Overflow automatically try to flag low-quality homework posts?

Tags: discussion

The phrase "Consider a" is almost purely a "homework" term. You'd never hear that from a sincere user.

Also things like: "the following is", "part 1" and, obviously, "assignment".

Should the system automatically flag questions like that?

These are copy-paste questions.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/227177/297832/ drops mic.

Comment: I was trying to **consider a lot** of reasons, why my **assignment** command `x = ...` does not work. Of all the possible reasons, **the following is** the most suspicious: I am not sure if in the **part 1** of my code (see above) I have properly initialized the variable `y`... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with someone asking a question about homework.  A bad question that's not about homework is every bit as bad as one that is.

As for low quality posts in general, Stack Exchange sites already do automatically flag low quality posts.

Comment: Understood, I buy it . thanks!!!